# Set and Set Complement of Uniform Distribution on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This questions first came to mind a few years ago when I was taking a course on real analysis as an undergraduate. I posed it to my instructor but he did not know a means of solving my inquiry. But to the point, does there exist a set (or is there a means of constructing a set) such that for a set of points $S \in [0,1]$ and $S^{C} \in [0,1]$ $S$ and $S^{C}$ both have measure $\frac{1}{2}$ and for any arbitrary sub-interval $(a,b)$ of $[0,1]$ the value $\mu_{S} = \mu (S \: \cap \: (a,b))=\mu (S^{C} \: \cap \: (a,b)) = \mu_{S^{C}}$ ? Just to clarify $S^{C}$ is the complement of $S$ on the unit interval, or put differently $S^{C} = S^{complement} \: \cap \: [0,1]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such measurable set.  If there were you can get a contradiction as follows.

Note that $\mu_S\ll\mu$ because $\mu(A)=0$ implies $\mu_S(A)=\mu(A\cap S)=0$, so the [Radon Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) applies: there exists a function $f$ such that $\mu_S(A)=\int_A f dx$, unique up to measure $0$ modifications. Calculate this Radon Nikodym derivative  two different ways.   On the one hand,  $f=\chi_S$, the indicator function of $S$, since $\mu_S(A)=\int_A \chi_S(x)dx$. On the other, it is the constant function $1/2$.  (Evaluate $F(x)=\mu_S([0,x]) = x/2$, and so on.)
These two formulas do not agree almost everywhere.

Comment: So unfortunately, I don't quite understand why the RN derivative is equal to the indicator function $\chi_{S}$. Could you please expand?

Comment: @DavidG.  I have edited my answer.  I hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: I don't see why $\mu (A) = 0$ since $A = (a,b)$ wouldn't it necessarily be the case that $\mu (A) = b-a$?

Comment: The condition for $\mu_S\ll\mu$ is that whenever $\mu(A)=0$ we also have $\mu_S(A)=0$, too.  Which is satisfied by your $\mu_S$.

Comment: Could you clarify why $\mu_{S} \ll \mu$? It seems to me that the relation should be $\mu_{s} = \frac{1}{2} \mu$ which still holds when $\mu (A) = 0$

Comment: The condition for applying  the Radon Nikodym theorem is that $\mu_S$ be absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$; the meaning of that is that whenever $\mu(A)=0$ it follows that $\mu_S(A)=0$.  The uniqueness a.e. of the Radon Nikodym derivative is what gives the contradiction.  You know the derivative is $1/2$, and you should (now) know that it is also $\chi_S$.

Answer (score 1):

By a standard argument $\mu(S\cap (a,b))=\mu(S^{c}\cap (a,b))$ for every subinterval $(a,b)$ implies $\mu(S\cap A)=\mu(S^{c}\cap A)$ for every Bore  set $A$. Taking $A=S$ we get a  contradiction.

Comment: I understand your point, however, I'm inclined to believe that $S$ cannot equal $A$ as I don't see how $S$ is an interval.

Comment: If you extend the equality from intervals to measurable sets you can then take $A=S$.

Comment: Though this is true, that breaks the statement of the question and circumvents the basis of the question. The subintervals are there to illustrated uniform distribution of points across the unit interval